# Add # comments on block with Sublime text 2

Tags: comments, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, shortcut

I would like to know the steps to add # comments on a block with sublime.

basically to go from a code like this

```
console.log "code here"
console.log "code there"
```

Apply the short-cut, then obtain a code like this

```
# console.log "code here"
# console.log "code there"
```

Right now I can only remove them with the **multiple cursor** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

The traditional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> doesn't work because it provides a comment like this :

```
//console.log "code here"
//console.log "code there"
```

Comment: So do you want lines with `console.log` to be commented with `#`'s or do you want to select some text and insert `#`'s at the start of the line?

Comment: I would like to select the lines and insert `#` at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a macro

```
[
    {"command": "split_selection_into_lines"},
    {"command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol", "extend": false}},
    {"command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "# "}}
]
```

Then a keymapping:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": { "file": "Packages/User/Snippets/test_snippets/tmp_comment.sublime-macro" } }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create macro is definitely what I am looking for, this will help more than one .

Comment: I tried the keymapping but it doesn't seem to respond to the mapping `Ctrl + Shift + i`. can you provide the steps to get this working?

Comment: Maybe that particular sequence is already mapped to a function.  Give [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) a try, or maybe first just try a different keymapping.

Comment: Tried a whole bunch of sequences, still doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what else tell you that could help, given the lack of info you are providing.  Keymaps should go in your `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` file.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for **line comment**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for **block comment**

Comment: This doesn't work in my case, because it adds this type of comment `//`